How to use another version of node to exec a commands in electron app?
I'm trying to figure out how to work with the Electron. Everything works great but I have a problem.
I have:

The electron app for a project manipulation
A few node.js versions on my device

My actions:

Choose a directory of a project
Press a button which pass the project path and "yarn install" command to the main process handler.

Main handler:
import { ipcMain } from 'electron';
import { exec } from 'node:child_process';

ipcMain.handle(
  'run-command',
  async (
    _event,
    {
      path,
      command,
    }: {
      path: string;
      command: string;
    },
  ) =>
    new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      exec(command, { cwd: path }, (error, stdout, stderr) => {
        if (error) {

          reject(new Error(`Command failed: ${command}\n${stderr}`));
          return;
        }

        resolve(stdout);
      });
    }),
);

But this command returns an error because of wrong node version.
I want to use the default node version of my OS (18.18.2), but the app uses old (11.5.0).
May be it's possible to use different node.js version for any project?
I just want to run some commands for a project in its context like manually in the terminal.
Could someone explain, how can I do it? Thank you for your attention and any advices!

The solution is here:
nvm in child process
exec("source path/to/nvm.sh && nvm use 14 && mycommand")
In my case there was no nvm.sh (I dunno why), so I reinstalled it and it appeared.
